# (Heroku) run python script 24/7

Tags: python, ubuntu, heroku

I have a python script and some other txt files and I want to run it 24/7 in a server.So, I found Heroku,but I have some problems when I follow the instuctions/commands.The commands are here:
[image: commands]

...but,I get some errors.Below, I show you the commands I run in my terminal and the output I receive.
[image: picture]
My files are here: [image: files]
I want your help.What should I do to solve this error?

Comment: You shouldn't post code/errors as pictures...
However, the error does say that the commit has already been built. Maybe create a new commit and try again. BTW the commit you made in the picture didn't change anything, so it would still complain.

Comment: Where do those files live?  According to that screenshot, your repository contains no files at all.  You pushed an empty repo.

Comment: I'm concerned about your project name "clicker".  You do understand that Heroku stuff runs on a completely separate  computer.  It won't have access to your desktop.  If you're trying to "click" things in local apps, that won't work.

Comment: My app don't "click" things in local apps,but in web.So, I ask you again: how can I solve these errors?What can I do?